# Check if event target is a file or a value

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, react-redux

So basically what my question originates from is me trying to upload an image using a class based react component but I'm having trouble because image is event.target.files whereas other fields I have such as name and title are event.target.values. So far my state and setState look like this.

```
state = {
    name: '',
    title: '',
    caption: '',
    image: ''
}

onChange = e => {
    // I think conditional will go here
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
}
```

How could I create a conditional which checks whether the event.target is a value or a file? Another side question. Since the image is a file and not a value is my state set up correctly?

**UPDATE**

I implemented the setState directly into the onChange in the jsx. Now its not actually uploading the image. Im using the django rest api and i get a 400 bad request. Here is my onSubmit.

```
onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, title, caption, image } = this.state;
    const info = { name, title, caption, image };
    this.props.addInfo(info);

    this.setState({
        name: '',
        title: '',
        caption: '',
        image: null
    })
}
```

Why am I getting a 400 bad request and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you write different function for image

```
  handleImageChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
  image: e.target.files[0]
   })
  };
```